# Formatting BigDecimal to currency String with three decimal places

Tags: java

I need to format numbers to currency. The problem is that I need three decimal digits.

At the moment I have two. The code I have is:

```
private static Locale getLocaleFromCurrency(String strCode) {

    for (final Locale locale : NumberFormat.getAvailableLocales()) {
        final String code = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).getCurrency().getCurrencyCode();
        if (strCode.equals(code)) {
            return locale;
        }
    }  
    return null;
}
```

and

```
private String toCurrency(BigDecimal value, String currency) {
    if (value == null) {
        value = new BigDecimal(0);
    }
    return NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(getLocaleFromCurrency(currency)).format(value);
}
```

At the moment, I get:

```
$1.24
$10.20
```

but I would like to receive:

```
$1.242
$10.195
```

Comment: did you have a look at DecimalFormat?

Comment: Yes, I'm not interested in it. This method is used application-wide.

Comment: You never declared that you need three digits in your code. You should take a look at `Numberformat.setMinimumFractionDigits(int)`.

Comment: @MCEmperor thanks, I didn't know the appropriate method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `NumberFormat` methods `setMaximumFractionDigits` and `setMinimumFractionDigits`:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(getLocaleFromCurrency(currency));
numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
return numberFormat.format(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setMinimumFractionDigits(3)` and `format.setMaximumFractionDigits(3)` of `NumberFormat` class.